# openstack-Neutron-LBaaS 503 returned by Haproxy

Tags: openstack, haproxy, openstack-neutron

Recently I am working on LBaaS service. When I set up a pool and it serves,
the haproxy process randomly returns **503**:

```
503 Service Unavailabe
```

No server is available to handle this request

And I am pretty sure when this problrm happened, **member servers are up.**

Anyone can help me abt this problem?

PS:when i first build members in the loadbalancer，the status is active, however,it will turn to inactive in a few minutes. And I find a way to resolve this via executing

```
echo -e 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n<serverX>' | nc -l -p
```

then the status of members turns to active.

Answer (score 0):

Ahaaaa...
Finally i got it, I am really careless..
i should use **while true** when i execute 
echo -e 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n' | nc -l -p
otherwise, this command will be only executed by once.